# How to parse json column in MySQL Version < 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a column called `inventory`.

```
id ..... inventory
```

the content of this column is:

```
{"STC1":{"count":"1"},"STC2":{"count":0}}
```

the `count` value is variable. 
I don't want to use application side, I want to use sql.

for example

what I want:

```
... where STC1.count > 0
```

or

```
... where STC1.count > 1 or STC2.count < 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, according to [the official MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), the JSON support has been introduced for the 5.7.8 version, it isn't available natively for older versions.

For MySQL < 5.7.8, this JSON content is just a string, MySQL has nothing to extract structured data from it.

At best you'll be abble to check `WHERE inventory LIKE '%"STC1":{"count":"0"%'` to detect the row with a `STC1` at `0` or something like that but not much more, and it will rapidly becoming really hairy to do anything complex.

In general it's better to store atomic data to avoid this kind of problem.